# Ajax html response breaks

Tags: html, json, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

My Issue is if I print out html as php variable the output works absolutely fine. Example,

```
    $html = "<tag>some<tag>
    <othertag>other</tab>
    blah blah blah
    ";
    echo $html;
```

This is just an example. But when I pass this as php variable through AJAX, this html breaks. example,

```
success: function( data ) {
    jQuery('somediv).html(html);
},
```

This is an example, I am actually passing hundreds of lines of html which is an output of a wordpress shortcode.

```
function load_ajax_content(){
    ob_start();
    echo do_shortcode('[my shortcode]'); //Plenty of html with javascript output
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    wp_send_json_success( $output));
    die();
}
```

I am totally stuck here, Same shortcode and this variable working fine if I output as php variable anywhere

```
echo $output;
```

but, passing though ajax output with jQuery.html breaking it. There is no ajax error in this process

```
wp.ajax.send( 'load_ajax_content', {
    data: {
        var: param,
        
    },
    success: function( data ) {
            jQuery('somediv').html(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('fail');
        console.log(e);

    }
});
```

Comment: ajax means transferring XML data (_A_ synchronous _X_ ML _A_ nd _J_ avascript). An XML document _must_ have one single root document element and everything else must be embedded within that root. You cannot just send plain HTML as if it were valid XML. You sould escape your XML or send it in a CDATA  section in a properly formatted XML message

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Could you please share sample code on how to do that?